# android: can navigation drawer (ActionBarDrawerToggle) show itself on init/default

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer (ActionBarDrawerToggle), it is always hidden after init, can I have it shown first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(/**Your content View**/) 
     mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(/**Your drawer**/);
     mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
    }
```